# Blender rig problem

Tags: python, rigify

Trying to add automatic bone weight to my rig. Blender stops responding and i have to quit it. When i open the file it says “for security reasons automatic execution of python scripts in this file was disabled”

And this goes on for an infinite loop.

Comment: Hello & Welcome to https://blender.stackexchange.com/ Please try to use a title that reflects the content of your question so that it is easier to see what this is about. Also, in this case it might be helpful if you share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/, because without that information it might be difficult to answer your question. You may also want to look at the [Help Center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) posts, starting with this article: [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How many deform bones do you have and how many triangles does you mesh have?